# Bootstrap 4 Card with dropdown menu on the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 and I have a card:

```
<div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-header">
    Featured
  </div>
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to put an icon on the right header with a dropdown menu.

How do I do this? I've been googling for samples but found none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `icon` and `dropdown` then wrap them inside `<div class="float-right">`

Check out the [Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/I1zm5eZ2a3) I created.